# Is there any way to discover the capacitance, voltage rating, and temperature coefficient of these MLCCs?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, capacitance, mlcc

Is there any way to discover the capacitance, voltage rating, and temperature coefficient of these 3 MLCCs shown in the pictures below using an inexpensive tool I can purchase? What is meant by the 2.2 uF here? Is this supposed to be the combined capacitance or just the capacitance for the last capacitor? Would you say these are in parallel or in series? They look like they are in parallel to me except for the fact that the left most one's top end is on a different path that connects to a pin on the microcontroller. How would the total capacitance be calculated in this scenario then?

[image]

[image]

Here is the full image of the boards front and back:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

103 = 1+0+ 000 or 10,000pF (10nF). Similarly, 104 is 100nF or 0.1uF.

2.2uF is rated at just what it says, and it applies just to C4.

It’s rare to have the values marked on the PCB and extremely rare to have the MLCC parts themselves marked.

It’s not uncommon to parallel capacitors of greatly different value to get low impedance over a wide frequency range (higher values may have more parasitic inductance). The effective value is just the sum of the capacitances.

You can buy a capacitance meter or an inexpensive hobbyist open-board component tester that will give you approximate values, however the caps may measure higher or lower than rated by a considerable amount depending on bias. Most likely they could measure a bit high or ‘on’ with a meter, but could be 1/5 of the rated value at full rated voltage.

That still leaves the tempco and dielectric type, voltage rating, voltage coefficient etc. unknown. If you understand the circuit most of that will be obvious, but not always. The 100nF and 2.2uF appear to be non-critical power supply filter/bypass parts (possibly a low pass filter with the 100 ohm resistor). The 10nF part may be associated with a signal.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @spehro. I am trying to find someone that I can pay to help me understand this simple pcb board (20 components) better as a way to learn more about electronics. I am very much new to electronics in general and so any help would be appreciated. If you would be willing and interested contact me at electrical.engineer76434@gmail.com. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to discover the capacitance, voltage rating, and temperature coefficient of these 3 MLCCs shown in the pictures below using an inexpensive tool I can purchase?

No. You can fairly easily measure the capacitances but temperature coefficient and voltage rating are harder; these are not easy to measure. Fortunately you don't need to determine the exact specifications in order to choose adequate caps for the circuit if you are planning on duplicating or repairing it.

The capacitance values are marked on the board but in sort of nonintuitive form. The rightmost capacitor is definitely 2.2 uF. The middle one is 100 nF since it's marked with 104, as in 1.0 x 10^4 pF (or 100 nF). The left one is 10 nF by the same reasoning since it's marked 103.

As for voltage, the best way is probably to turn the circuit on and measure the voltage on the pins. If you can't turn the device on, check the datasheet for the chip to see what voltages are expected here. This looks like a switching power supply, and this chip looks like the controller. Therefore the chip datasheet might indicate a wide range of possible voltages allowable on these pins. You might need to apply some other knowledge about this circuit to figure out the voltage range expected on those caps. As with all capacitors, these caps require a bit of de-rating. This means that you should select a rated voltage 50%-100% higher (1.5x-2x) than the actual maximum expected on these pins.

Temperature coefficient isn't so important. Judging from the pictures of your circuit, these capacitors are not performing a precise filtering function where their exact capacitance value must be stable over temperature. Use X7R temperature class if possible. X5R is probably fine too unless it's getting very hot in the enclosure. Avoid using C0G capacitors since they are tuned/resonant circuits.

Comment: Your capacitor values are low by a factor of 10. 104 is 1, 0, and four 0s, making it 100000 pf, or 0.1 uF or 100 nF.  103 is 0.01 uF or 10 nF.

Comment: Ah right, yeah that’s more correct sounding, 0.1 and 0.01 uF. Just fixed my answer.

Comment: @Zane I've added some additional pictures of the entire board. I'm not very experienced with measuring voltage on pins of an IC on a board. Where would be a good place to put the black and red probes on this board to measure the voltage for each of these MLCCs?

Answer (score 0):

Since these are bypass and not filtering capacitors, the temperature coefficients and change in bias with voltage are relatively unimportant. The values only need to be approximately those written on the PCB, so no need to measure.